# Postgres unique constraint not deferrable in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, unique-constraint

I created an unique constraint in PostgreSQL database and set it to `deferrable initially deferred`.

For example, I have unique key on column `order_num` and I have two rows in database like this:

```
id      order_num           description
1               1           'something no 1'
2               2           'something no 2'
```

When I tried to do this script on database (even in this unlogical order), it worked fine:

```
begin transaction;
    insert into some_table(id, order_num, description) values(3, 2, 'something no 3');
    delete from some_table where id = 2;
end transaction;
```

But when I tried to do this from application (even in logical order, first delete, then insert) it said `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

Does someone know what is problem with hibernate? How can I set deferrable on it?

EDIT:
Ok, unique constraint consists of `id_ri_content`, `id_structure_table_column` and `element_order`.

When I run transaction from PG admin, log shows this:

`2014-03-17 13:45:15 CET LOG: statement: begin transaction; insert into ri_content_cell(id_ri_content_cell, id_ri_content, id_ri_structure_table_column, element_order, content) values(118, 41, 226, 2, '3'); insert into ri_content_cell(id_ri_content_cell, id_ri_content, id_ri_structure_table_column, element_order, content) values(119, 41, 228, 2, 'Zika'); delete from ri_content_cell where id_ri_content_cell in (120,121); end transaction;`

While running the same in hibernate from java session bean method produce this error log:

`2014-03-17 13:54:25 CET LOG:  execute : select nextval ('ri_content_cell_seq')
2014-03-17 13:54:25 CET LOG:  execute : select nextval ('ri_content_cell_seq')
2014-03-17 13:54:25 CET LOG:  execute : insert into ri_content_cell (content, element_order, id_ri_content, id_ri_structure_table_column, id_ri_content_cell) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
2014-03-17 13:54:25 CET DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '2', $2 = '2', $3 = '41', $4 = '226', $5 = '136'
2014-03-17 13:54:25 CET ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_ri_content_cell"
2014-03-17 13:54:25 CET DETAIL:  Key (id_ri_content, id_ri_structure_table_column, element_order)=(41, 226, 2) already exists.`

Comment: This is a SQLException, right? If it's a SQLException, then it comes from PostgreSQL, not from Hibernate. So either you have several transactions, or the constraint is not really deferred, or some other constraint is violated, or you didn't really delete the row.

Comment: I think it is hibernate exception, however full exception name is:
12:09:32,262 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-12) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
12:09:32,262 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-12) ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_ri_content_cell"

Comment: Log the whole transaction at the PostgreSQL level. Edit `postgresql.conf` and set `log_statement = 'all'` and make sure there's a useful `log_line_prefix`. Then get the whole series of statements from the PostgreSQL logs. I won't be surprised to see a `SET CONSTRAINTS` statement during connection setup.

Comment: Post ther full stack trace, instead of a log statement which doesn't even contain the exception class name.

Comment: I wrote the EDIT part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if JTA is set to TRUE for the data source that Hibernate is using.

Comment: Thanks, after I set jta="true" in the datasource it works fine.